# Set default terminal for elevated command prompt

Tags: terminal, cmd.exe, windows-11, windows-terminal

You can [set a default terminal](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windows-terminal-as-your-default-command-line-experience/#default-terminal-setting) in developer settings section of windows settings. If you launch a batch file with elevated privileges, it still uses the old shell. How do I set the default shell for elevated processes?

Comment: According to [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/10276), it seems like this is currently not possible.